# Android Yahoo Aviate Launcher Page Swipe Effects

Tags: java, android, tabs, swipe

This is one of the screenshots of Yahoo Aviate Launcher:

[image]

What I wanna do is like this. When users swipe to the rightest page of the launcher, which is the list of apps ordered by alphabet, the left side of this screenshot can still remain part of the left page. It's like these two pages are on the same page, and due to the size of the screen we can only see the partial view. This design gives user a visual hint of swiping left.

I want to do this in my app, but I have no idea how to implement this. Pretty close to swipe tab view but I don't know how to keep the left page visible when swiping to the right page.

Comment: Why aren't you using a DrawerLayout and treating this as a drawer ? ( https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html )

Comment: As far as I know, if I swipe out the navigation drawer, it will disappear from the screen. But what I want to do is to make the view remain partial on the screen instead of removing it entirely. Is there a way to use navigation drawer and get the same effect that i mentioned?

Answer (score 0):

You should use a SlidingPaneLayout

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/SlidingPaneLayout.html

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0pTAEmAErBc

Comment: Thanks, this can really do a half-close drawer, but there's still something different from Aviate effect. Sorry for dismissing this part in the previous comment. Just take the YouTube video as an example, Pane A doesn't move with B and actually A is covered by B when B is out. 
What I want to do is like that I can swipe the "shared side" of Pane A & B, and at the meanwhile, the swiped Pane can remain partial on the screen.

Comment: Well, you can't really expect to find it exactly like you want it right out of the box, I think the SlidingPaneLayout will give you everything you need to START (!!) with. Extend it and provide an onPanelSlide listener, use the value there to move/pad the fragment to get the desired effect. I really think that if you start it should be a fairly short task

Comment: Thank you! 
You really give me a great push on a very start.

Comment: Let me know how it went, if it failed please explain and I will either give it a shot or think of something new. If it worked please accept my answer